# Getting the list of available parameters for a Wacom device

Tags: 10.04, xorg, input-devices, wacom

How would one go about obtaining the list of parameter names for
a recognized Wacom device that can be manipulated with the `xsetwacom` tool?

To be more specific, I'm looking for names applicable to `<param>` below:

```
xsetwacom set <wacom_device>  <param>  <value>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsetwacom --list param` should do it.

Comment: Thanks. How did I miss that! (Actually, I know why: there is no man page on xsetwacom on Lucid.)

Answer (score 3):

Murat gave the right answer to this question already. This is just to add some knowledge on top of it.

```
xinput --list-props <device_name>
```

also shows some properties that can be modified/retrieved through the xinput interface. However, property names here may not be compatible with `xsetwacom`.

Comment: by any chances do you know of any resources that explain clearly how xorg, xinput, the kernel etc. interact?

Answer (score 2):

Note that editing the wacom-specific config file may be better than running xsetwacom every time you reboot or ALT+F7 back to the X desktop.

I just recently figured out how that worked and wrote up a little how-to posting on the Ubuntu forum:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588459

Comment: Thanks for the how-to. There are many ways to "hook" a xsetwacom script, but I agree that the xorg setting seems more natural and probably faster.